# Why are there many languages using JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, programming-languages, bytecode

I see a large list of programming languages [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages). What is the reason of using JVM and what are other options for a new programming language?

Comment: JVM is not the best VM to host any language different from Java itself. But on the other hand, Java ecosystem provides tons of ready to use libraries, and therefore a seamless interoperability with Java is beneficial and overweights the semantic and performance oddities of the platform. And more, in some environments you can *only* use JVM and nothing else, and in such case it's nice to be able to escape Java slavery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

byte code can be run on any system with a JVM.  If you are creating a new language, or porting an old one, all you need do is generate byte code (much simpler than optimal code for a real machine) and you are done.

Note: many of the JVM ports are faster if you use a JVM as well as much more work has gone into optimising the native code.